# Direct Proof: $\forall x \in\mathbb{ Z} , x^2-x \geq 0$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm currently in a Discrete Math course at my university (not a homework question) so I'm fairly new at proofs (only 1 week into the course). 
I'm a bit confused at the best approach to proving statements and furthermore, how to properly write them. I've split this question into cases because I'm not sure how to prove this in a simpler way. This is what I've done:

Proof: True. Assume $x \in \mathbb{ Z}$.

Case 1: Assume $x = 0$. Then $x^2-x = 0$ which satisfies $x^2-x \geq 0$

Case 2: Assume $x > 0$. Let $x = 2$. Then $x^2-x = 2$ which satisfies $x^2-x \geq 0$

Case 3: Assume $x < 0$. Let $x = -2$. Then $x^2-x = 6$ which satisfies $x^2-x \geq 0$

Would this be considered a sufficient proof?

EDIT:

Sorry, I do know there is another method of solving this as I saw the answer that the practice problem provided. They solved it by completing the square and arrived at this:

$x^2-x = (x- \frac{1}{2})^2- \frac{1}{4} \geq - \frac{1}{4}$

and that was all that was there. Now, I understand the math but not why it's sufficient enough to qualify as a proof. Because to me it's no different than the original statement $x^2-x \geq 0$.

Comment: If you are asked to prove that some thing is true **for all** $x$ you cannot just take one particular value of $x$. Besides $x=2$ does not fall in to case 3.

Comment: You can check how to write integer symbol in the edit made. :)

Comment: Why did you chose those specific cases (x=2)? Proving something means you to consider all cases. And even in a proof by case distinction you shouldn't lose generality, which means you can chose those three specific cases, but you shouldn't assign specific values to them (x=2 and x=-2 in your case)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah sorry you're right, that should have been -2 with a result of 6. I fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$x^2-x=x(x-1)$$ so $$x^2-x\geq 0$$ if $$x\geq 1$$ or $$x\le 0$$

Comment: This was what I was originally drawn to doing in the beginning. I can intuitively see why $x(x-1) \geq 0$ but is that enough to say that that's my proof? So I assume that $x \in  \mathbb{ Z}$ (to cover your if and or condition) and say that since $x(x-1) \geq 0$ then that satisfies that $x^2-x \geq 0$?

Comment: Yes, this i have written in my answer, $$x^2-x=x(x-1)$$

Answer (score 2):

For any $n \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $n^2\geq0$.

We also, know that if $n\leq 0$, then $(-n)\geq0$.
This implies $n^2-n \geq 0.$-------------$(*)$

Now, if $n\geq 1$.
Now, since, $n$ is positive, we can multiply $n$ to both sides.
 We get $n^2\geq n \implies n^2-n\geq 0.$--------$(**)$.

Since $\mathbb{Z} \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ and it doesn't contain any number between $(0,1)$. Therefore, combining $(*)$ and $(**)$; It follows that $$n^2-n\geq 0 \enspace \forall \enspace n \in \enspace \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 2):

Showing $x^2-x = (x- \frac{1}{2})^2- \frac{1}{4} \geq - \frac{1}{4}$ is enough because:

- $x^2-x$ is an integer
- $x^2-x \geq \frac{-1}{4}$

Therefore, $x^2-x \geq 0$

But the "best answer" really depends on which tools you are "allowed" to use. With this I mean, should we consider ourselves familiar with rational and real numbers, or rather avoid them completely? With just integers, I'd try to proof by induction that $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}, x^2 \geq x$. See:

- This statement is true for $x \leq 0$ as $x^2$ is always non-negative
- Assume it is also true for a given $x \geq 0$. Then, $(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2*x +1 \geq x^2+1 \geq x+1 $

Comment: I guess my thing was that when I sat down to solve this, completing the square never even crossed my mind. But, as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner mentioned in his answer, $x^2-x = x(x-1)$ is sufficient and was an answer I came to, I guess it just didn't click that that was also a sufficient enough proof. Also, I'm sure it'll be fine in the coming days to use those things (it was never stipulated to us that we are not allowed to use them) but we just haven't learned them yet. We were only briefly introduced to proof by induction so far.

Comment: Proof by induction is a basic ressource when working with naturals/integers, so you may want to examine that. In its most basic form, you just STEP 1: Prove that a dependent-on-x-statement is true for x=1 and STEP 2: Prove that, if it's true for x=k, then it' s also true for k+1. The logic is that now the statement is true for x=1, therefore it's true for x=2, therefore it's true for x=3 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

We want to show, that for every $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ it is $x^2-x\geq 0$. So $x(x-1)\geq 0$.

This product is greater then zero, if either every factor is positiv, or negativ.
The case, where one factor is zero is trivial.

So if $x>0$, then $x\geq 1$ and it is $x-1\geq 0$. So this holds. (both positiv)
If $x<0$, then $x-1<0$ obviously (both negativ).

If $x-1>0$, then $x>1$ (both positiv)

If $x-1<0$, then $x<1$ (both negativ)

[Keep in mind we 'made' the assumption, that neither factor is zero.]

Answer (score 0):

Option:

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Show $x^2\ge x$.

1)If $x \le 0$,

$x^2 \ge 0$, and $x \le 0$, inequality is true.

2) If $x >0$,

$x^2 \ge x$ is equivalent to $x \ge 1$.

(Division of inequality by $x >0$).

3)Altogether:

Inequality is valid for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.